# Accidently deleted /etc/environment file

Tags: ubuntu-18.04

I accidently deteleted my /etc/environment file in ubuntu using

sudo rm /etc/environment

So I just wanted to know how to recover the file. And also I haven't logged out since I deleted the file.
Please help

Comment: Probably more suited for askubuntu.com or unix.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you deleted by rm command you cannot restore, but if you write the command inside /etc you can create the file again.

```
sudo vi environment
```

and normally there supposed to have the following PATH. But, it depends on the server setting.

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
```

After that save this.

Comment: Is this command the only default that is present on installation?

Comment: If you write command, echo $PATH
Did you get any output? If you get, that was the value.

Comment: /home/akhil/bin:/home/akhil/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin

Comment: Great, save this into environment

Comment: Thanks! So, only PATH variable is defined in enviornment file by default?

Comment: Yes. That is for the environment variable [PATH]

Comment: Sorry, for asking such questions but should I write the PATH="/home/akhil/bin:/home/akhil/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin" or without ""?

Comment: With. Or you can set PATH in another way through bash profile.